# Identify caller

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link in some html which calls a javascript function I'm writing. The call must be inline so the code is as follows:

```
 <a href='#' onclick='quipManager.getQuip(1, $(this))'>Test</a>
```

In the getQuip function I use the this reference to modify the div which wraps the link by means of .parents()
e.g.

```
  getQuip: function (id, currentQuip) {
      alert(currentQuip.parents('.qtip').html());
  }
```

I need to keep the call inline, but what I'd like to know is if I can use it like this:

```
 <a href='#' onclick='quipManager.getQuip(1)'>Test</a>
```

and still have getQuip know which link called it so the following still works.

```
 getQuip: function (id) {
      var currentQuip = id.caller ???
      alert(currentQuip.parents('.qtip').html());
  }
```

Comment: Why *must* the call be inline?

Comment: Why do you need to keep that code in-line? O.o

Comment: Because the link is being constructed on the fly from a placeholder in a user created text document and I'm trying to keep things simple. It's a pretty ugly, kind of DIY CMS system, but it's last minute massive scope creep! I'll refine it if it hangs around for long.

Comment: I would have thought that adding a class would be simpler than adding an `onclick` atribute.

Comment: In this case the inline call is simpler. If the requirement isn't ditched in the next few days I will implement it through use of a css class and data element and extend the qtip library to add the required behaviour, but I'm looking for quick and dirty right now. Also I'm curious for the sake of it - it appears to be a gap in my javascript knowledge that I'd like to fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the answer is you can't :(

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like:

```
$('#element').click(function() {
    example.apply(this);
});

var example = function() {
    $(this).text("it worked");
}
```

`.apply` will allow you to change the default assignment of `this` within the example function, so you could change it to whatever element, and handle it the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/mwrX2/

Comment: he told that he wants it in-line

Comment: but question is - WHY ? (whoops, he deleted his comment, forget this comment)

Comment: umm - that's what i already have - ok so I use $(this) instead of this, but the same principle applies.

Comment: You can't take the argument against me not posting it inline, and then ask why I posted it inline... I'm confused by you.

Comment: so is your question answered?

Comment: no - lemme see if I can revise the question to be a bit clearer - I can see I've caused some confusion here.